# Error on return using a struct method - C++

Tags: c++, struct

I separated from a single file into a header and body files, but now have a problem.

I guess I am declaring something wrong but can't figure out what.

Body:

```
# include "GraphAL.h"


// A utility function to create a new adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode* GraphAL::newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight)
{
    struct AdjListNode* newNode =
            (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    newNode->dest = dest;
    newNode->weight = weight;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

Header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>


class GraphAL{
public:

    struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight);


    // A structure to represent a node in adjacency list
    struct AdjListNode
    {
        int dest;
        int weight;
        struct AdjListNode* next;
    };

    // A structure to represent an adjacency liat
    struct AdjList
    {
        struct AdjListNode *head; // pointer to head node of list
    };

    // A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
    // Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
    struct Graph
    {
        int V;
        struct AdjList* array;
    };
};
```

The error is:
" cannot convert ‘GraphAL::AdjListNode*’ to ‘AdjListNode*’ in return  "

Comment: `struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight);` must come after the definition of `struct AdjListNode`.  Also the use of malloc causes undefined behaviour, you could use `new` instead

Comment: lol indeed, thanks! I changed it to the end and at the body file I changed to "struct GraphAL::AdjListNode* GraphAL::newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight)".
Also, thanks for the advice on malloc, you are right.

Comment: You don't need to put struct in cases where you refer to a variable in C++ like: `struct AdjList* array`, you can just put `AdjList* array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully qualify return type in the implementation site:

```
GraphAL::AdjListNode* GraphAL::newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight)
```

In c++ use of `malloc/free` is discouraged for a couple of reasons; we tend to use new/delete instead:

```
AdjListNode* newNode =new AdjListNode;
```

There are a bunch of other things that can overally modernize and improve this snippet, but that I guess might cause confusion - if mentioned right now.

You may go ahead an do this:

```
auto GraphAL::newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight){
    //...
}
```

And:

```
auto newNode =new AdjListNode {dest, weight,nullptr};
```

Where `nullptr` is the proper **keyword** for null pointer value and `auto` is used for automatic type deduction.

I can go furthur and rewrite your code in a few short lines of declaration in header:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <utility>

class GraphAL{
public: 
    typedef std::forward_list<std::pair<int,int>> Graph;
};
```

Then:

```
#include <GraphAL.h>
GraphAL::Graph gr1;
gr1.emplace_front(1,1);
```

Choice of std container(`vector`, `list`, ...) depends on detailed implementation.

Have fun.